# Get user's location in background

Tags: iphone, ios, location, core-location

As I need user's location in background and I am getting user's location in `didUpdateLocation` . But due to this it consumes more battery .

I have implemented `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in background method but according to me `didUpdateLocation` is not working .

Any solution so i can consume **low battery** power and also get updated location of user frequently.

Comment: Give some code that you wrote

Comment: self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: in background's method [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]

Comment: but i think now did update is not receiving updated location

Comment: @apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689626/iphone-gps-battery-draining-extremely-fast

Comment: Have a look at this article http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/

Answer (score 0):

*"didUpdateLocation . But due to this it consumes more battery ."*

That's not totally true. You can adjust the level of precision that you need with didUpdateLocation. Depending on what accuracy you want, your device will only use cellular position data instead of your native GPS receiver turned on all the time, example:

Lower battery consumption and accuracy of 500 meters
**CLLocationAccuracy myaccuracy = 500.00;**

Maximum accuracy and maximum battery drainage you can have (requires the device to be plugged on a charger)
**CLLocationAccuracy myaccuracy = -1.0;**

You can also use constants if you're not sure about which value to choose:

extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation; <-- means -1.0 
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Now answering your question:

didUpdateLocation only works when you ask your locationManager to startUpdatingLocation.

When you use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, you're not getting any information from your GPS unit. When using this method, your app will be waken up once your phone changes from one cell tower to another (traveling by train or car for example). When your app is waken by it, you need to implement:

```
id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
if (locationValue) {     
    NSLog(@"locationValue received, now needs to start updateLocation again");
    //your code goes here
}
```

inside your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

}

Then you can start your regular startUpdatingLocation again in order to receive didUpdateLocation notifications. Alternatively, you can check Apple's documentation and see if  the launchOptions carry any position information upon app start.